# async tasks inside async each : Callback to be run after all task and sub tasks completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am using async.js for this purpose.  I basically iterate all array and  run a delete using aysnc.each.

```
var async = require("async");
var fs = require('fs');


var files = ['a.log', 'b.log', 'c.log'];


async.each(files, function(file, cb) {
  if(file == 'a.log') {
    console.log('its A');
    fs.unlink(file, function(err) {  //delete the particular file
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(file + ' has been Deleted');
    });
  }

  if(file == 'b.log') {
    console.log('its B');
    fs.unlink(file, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(file + ' has been Deleted');
    });
  }

  if(file == 'c.log') {
    console.log('its C');
    fs.unlink(file, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(file + ' has been Deleted');
    });
  }
  cb();
}, function(err) {
  console.log('all done');
});
```

My output for now..where the deletion finish later.

```
its A
its B
its C
all done
a.log has been Deleted
b.log has been Deleted
c.log has been Deleted
```

What I'd like to achieve is the output to be something like below where the callback will only run after all each and sub task(delete file) completed.

```
its A
its B
its C
a.log has been Deleted
b.log has been Deleted
c.log has been Deleted
all done  //would like this
```

Comment: Try moving the calling of `async.each` iteratee callback (`cb()`) inside the `fs.unlink` callback

Comment: move to all 3 fs.unlink callback?

Comment: Yes... or you could refactor the code so it will only have one `fs.unlink`... Your example does have a lot of repetition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var async = require("async");
var fs = require('fs');

var files = ['a.log', 'b.log', 'c.log'];
var dict = { 'a.log': 'A', 'b.log': 'B', 'c.log': 'C' };

async.each(files, function(file, cb) {
  console.log('its ' + dict[file]);
  fs.unlink(file, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err)
      cb(err)
    } else {
      console.log(file + ' has been Deleted');
      cb()
    }
  })
}, function(err) {
  console.log('all done');
});
```

You should move callback call inside unlink function. 
I also removed redundancy code.

Answer (score 1):

Your iteratee's callback is called too early (it does not wait for `fs.unlink` to complete).
You need to move the calling of it inside the `fs.unlink` callback:

```
async.each(files, function(file, cb) {
  if(file == 'a.log') {
    ...
  } else if(file == 'b.log') {
    ...
  } else if(file == 'c.log') {
    ...
  }
  ...
  fs.unlink(file, function(err) {
    ...
    cb();
    ...
  }
  ...
}, function(err) {
  console.log('all done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next

```
var async = require("async");
var fs = require('fs');


var files = ['a.log', 'b.log', 'c.log'];

async.each(files, function (file, cb) {
  console.log(file);
  fs.unlinkSync(file);  //delete the particular file
  console.log(file + ' has been Deleted');
  cb();
}, function (err) {

  console.log('error = ', err);
}
);
console.log('All done');
```